# Ковариантность параметров C++

Tags: ооп, c++

Всегда был уверен, что C++ поддерживает ковариантность в возвращаемых типах http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type, но не поддерживает аналогичный подход в параметрах. Вот тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821158/c-covariance-in-parameters, например, убеждают, что ковариантность параметров - это нарушение принципа Лисков  [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2). Однако следующий простой пример компилируется и прекрасно работает. Компилятор mingw 4.8.2. Используется Qt, но это не суть важно. Главный вопрос: это частный случай конкретного компилятора или на сегодня стандартная возможность и код переносим?

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

class Data
{
public:
    Data() {}
    virtual ~Data() {}
    virtual void testMethod() {qDebug() << "Data";}
};

class DataInherited : public Data
{
public:
    DataInherited() {}
    void testMethod() {qDebug() << "DataInherited";}
};

class DataUser
{
public:
    DataUser() {}
    virtual ~DataUser() {}
    virtual Data* testOut() { return new Data; }
    virtual void testIn(Data* a) { a->testMethod();}
};

class DataUserInherited : public DataUser
{
public:
    DataUserInherited() {}
    DataInherited* testOut() { return new DataInherited; }
    void testIn(DataInherited* a) { a->testMethod();}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    DataUser* user = new DataUserInherited;
    Data* data = user->testOut(); // Возвращает объект класса DataInherited
    data->testMethod();           // Выводит в консоль "DataInherited"
    user->testIn(data);           // Выводит в консоль "DataInherited"

    DataUserInherited* userInherited = new DataUserInherited;
    userInherited->testIn((DataInherited*)data); // Выводит в консоль "DataInherited"

    delete data;
    delete user;
    delete userInherited;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Ссылки на wiki содержат лишние символы

Comment: поправил, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы в своём тесте не полностью воспроизвели пример с SO.

Если методу `void DataUserInherited::testIn(DataInherited* a)` добавить спецификатор `override`, то пример не скомпилируется. Это из-за того, что вы думаете, что **переопределили** виртуальную функцию, а на самом деле просто **перегрузили** её.

У `void DataUserInherited::testIn(DataInherited* a)` другой статический тип параметра, соответственно, другая сигнатура. То есть, для компилятора это другой метод с таким же названием.

А работает это так, как Вы ожидали, потому что метод `void Data::testMethod();` виртуальный. Вы просто реализовали паттерн [Шаблонный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). Вызов `testIn()` попадает то классу `DataUser`, то `DataUserInherited`, но вызов `testMethod()` по виртуальной таблице в обоих случаях `DataInherited::testMethod()`.

Comment: Однако верно, спасибо!